# Android Studio - SVN inital Commit dosn't work with a big project

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, visualsvn, svncommit

i have a Problem to commit to SVN.

**Infos:**
I migrated a Project from eclipse to android studio.
Everything worked.

Now I created a new Repository on my VisualSVN Server (Windows).
I can browse the Repo through *VCS -> Browse VCS Repository -> Browse Subversion Repository*
(like the Repo i created for the eclipse Project - whitch works)

I also enabled the VCS-Option for the Project

**Problem:**
Now i want to Upload my Project to the SVN Server
*right Click on the Project(for ContexMenue) -> Subversion -> Commit Directory*
and, after a while, i got the following error:

```
08:43:15 Throwable
     Too many events posted
     java.lang.Throwable
     at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.FrequentEventDetector.eventHappened(FrequentEventDetector.java:60)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueueImpl.queueSession(RefreshQueueImpl.java:96)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueueImpl.execute(RefreshQueueImpl.java:65)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.launch(RefreshSessionImpl.java:107)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueue.refresh(RefreshQueue.java:56)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueue.refresh(RefreshQueue.java:42)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.NewVirtualFile.refresh(NewVirtualFile.java:82)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile.refresh(VirtualFile.java:670)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.update.RefreshVFsSynchronously.refresh(RefreshVFsSynchronously.java:79)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.update.RefreshVFsSynchronously.updateChangesImpl(RefreshVFsSynchronously.java:128)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.update.RefreshVFsSynchronously.updateChanges(RefreshVFsSynchronously.java:107)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper$CommitProcessor.customRefresh(CommitHelper.java:452)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper.generalCommit(CommitHelper.java:266)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper.access$500(CommitHelper.java:56)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper$3$1.run(CommitHelper.java:169)
     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
     at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper$3.run(CommitHelper.java:165)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

08:43:16 0 files committed, 1471 files failed to commit: inital Commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem today, for me worked following solution:

1. Commit your project using a SVN Tool external to Android Studio (I used Tortoise SVN)
2. After that you can use Android Studio to commit any further changes